# Есть ли возможность задать стиль для отдельного элемента Bottom Navigation View?

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view, android-menu

Дизайнеры постарались и создали один из элементов меню отличным от других?
Сейчас использую обычную кнопку в дополнении к меню, но это создает много неудобств.

Есть ли возможность задать свой стиль для отдельного элемента BottomNavigationView?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]